# Russian children's book about a boy's first train journey

Tags: identification-request, russian-language

This is probably a Soviet-era children's book. It is about a boy's journey by train. As I remember it, not much happens plot-wise, but the boy's sense of wonder makes everything he encounters (The washbasin! This is how the door works! This is how they serve tea on the train!) seem marvelous. I think the book is meant to introduce young children to these phenomena. My mother read this book (in Chinese translation) to me when I was a child. I would love to know the name of the book.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess would be "What I Saw" by [Boris Zhitkov](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boris_Zhitkov). But I don't know if it was translated in other languages.

Comment: I looked at the description of this book online and it may very well be the one I am looking for. Thank you very much!